# Wordpress: How do I make definition lists easily editable from the back end?

Tags: wordpress, admin, user-experience

I have a CV page i created for a client: http://sharondrew.com/cv/

She would like to be able to easily edit this but wordpress admin does not give formatting options for these tags.

I am new to wordpress - what is the best approach to create a simple way fro my client to edit this text without screwing the formatting?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) Use a table. This is tabular data, after all, isn't it?

2) A more advanced solution, but probably overkill here, would be the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin with the *paid* [Repeater Field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/) add-on. This would require you to create a custom post type for the CV and to write template to display the data stored in the (repeatable) custom fields you created for the 'CV Post Type'.